# Bottom:0 Navbar doesn't seem well on mobile devices like chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

As you see in the image above, I'm creating a one-page website which all pages are 100vh long and on sliding down the navbar sticks to the top but on the opening page, I show the navbar stuck to the bottom. The problem is when you open the page from a mobile device, the browser calculates the page as `100vh` but then puts it's address bar and makes the page `100++vh` which pushes my navbar out of the page. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill javascript library can solve your problem.